# How to verify a login through LDAP in Perl?

Tags: perl, authentication, ldap

I writed a small script that binds to an LDAP server and retrieves all users and user informations. Now I'd like to write another one that binds to the LDAP server and then tests a given login. How can I do that?

```
my $ldap = ldapConnect();
my $user = 'user';
my $pwd = 'pwd';
# TEST USER AND PWD BUT HOW?

sub ldapConnect {
my $ldap = Net::LDAP->new('192.168.*.*');
my $password = '***';
$ldap->bind('cn=Administrator,cn=Users,DC=***,DC=***', password=> $password);
return $ldap;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
my $ldap = ldapConnect();        # Connect
my $search = $ldap->search(      # Search for the user
    base   => 'DC=***,DC=***',
    scope  => 'sub',
    filter => "(&(uid=$user))",
    attrs  => ['dn']
);
die "not found" if not $search->count;

# Get the user's dn and try to bind:
my $user_dn = $search->entry->dn; 
$ldap->bind( $user_dn, password => $pass );
print +($ldap->error ? "Bad credentials" : "Success!"), "\n";
```

Comment: This is the official answer. See [How do I authenticate a user against the LDAP server?](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/directory/faq/perldap-faq.html#_ldap_10) in the Net::LDAP FAQ.

Comment: Wanted to make it clear. The above answer that Richard entered is the official answer. You connect with the admin account, search for the user's DN, and then try to bind with the user's DN and password. The link I gave just confirms Richard's answer.

Comment: Just tryed on my LDAP server, I always get *"not found"* error even though the user exists.

Comment: Ok I had to change uid with another attribute and now it works, thank you guys so much :)

Answer (score 6):

Instead of binding as an LDAP administrator, just bind as the user you want to test. If the bind succeeds, the login tests fine. If it fails, it doesn't. This way, you don't have to worry about re-implementing all the authentication logic the LDAP server does in Perl.

Alternatively, as [David W.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/368630/david-w) points out, if you need to search for the DN for the user (because the user name isn't the DN), you can first bind either anonymously (if the LDAP server is configured to accept that) or as a known user, search for the DN, then rebind as the user whose account you're trying to check. I suggest using a non-privileged user for the initial search, but of course your administrative user would work too.

Comment: This is a good strategy if this is possible. However, you might not know the User's full DN in LDAP. For example, your user login is the `sAMAccountName` field. The user enters that, but parts of the DN may differ via user account. In that case, you log in as the Admin user, search based upon `sAMAccountName`, then rebind using the user's DN and entered password.

Comment: @DavidW: Yes, that's true. Though in those cases, really an administrative user oughtn't be used for the initial bind. Either anonymous, or an unprivileged user would be better. I'll edit my answer to include your comment. Thank you.